# Cisco SLM248G Switch Hardware Reset

Tags: cisco, linksys, switch

We have two Cisco SLM248G switches within our environment.  After some research, it seems that one is causing a few problems because during heavy loads, it is sending transmissions to our firewall (Cisco RV082), causing it to reset frequently.  I figure it might be a voltage issue so we temporarily disconnected it which resolved the firewall crashing.  I noticed now that when attempting to access the switch, the admin page loads but after logging-in, the admin portal page does not load fully, see screenshot.  We cannot go further after initial log-in.

Even after a factory reset (reset button held for seconds), the issue continues as far as a page that does not fully load.  Is there any other workaround for completely resetting memory etc?

[image: SLM248G Switch Home screen]

Comment: Are you running NoScript?

Comment: We are not running NoScript and have tried Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  The other switch is accessible but runs a newer firmware.  I really wish I could access this one just so I can update the firmware.  Also, I updated our post to describe the issue better.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but my solution would be accidentally dropping those switches off the roof.  Several times to be sure.  They were garbage new, and they're end of life now, so they might be dying.  Time for an upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue with a few other Linksys SLM switches in that series. We had to use IE 6 on Windows XP to make it work. I ended up installing a VM with XP just to upgrade the firmware.